# React - TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderSidebaritem' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React - TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderSidebaritem' of undefined.
(anonymous function)

I have commented the line causing the issue. It seems like it has something to do with the binding of 'this'. I tried binding 'this' in the constructor of the Sidebar class but that didn't seem to resolve the issue.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import data from './pokemon.min.json';
import './index.css';

class Sidebaritem extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="pokemon" onClick = { () => this.props.onClick() } >
                {this.props.pokename}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Sidebar extends React.Component{
    constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context);
        this.renderSidebaritem = this.renderSidebaritem.bind(this);
    }

    renderSidebaritem(name){
        return (
            <Sidebaritem 
                pokename = {name} 
                onClick = { () => alert('You clicked me.') }
            />
        );
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="sidebar">
                <h1>POKEDEX</h1>
                <hr/>
                {
                  data.map(function(poke){
                    this.renderSidebaritem(poke.pokemon) // <- This line causes the issue. 
                  })
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Pokedescription extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
            data.map(function(poke){
                if(poke.id == 5){
                    return (
                        <div className="poke-description-wrapper">
                            <h1 className="poke-name">{poke.pokemon} (#{poke.id})</h1>
                            <div className="poke-image">
                                <img src={poke.url_image} alt={poke.pokemon}/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="poke-meta-description">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>Height:</b> <span className="poke-data">{poke.height}</span></td>
                                            <td><b>Weight:</b> <span className="poke-data">{poke.weight}</span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>Type1:</b> <span className="poke-data">{poke.type_1}</span></td>
                                            <td><b>Type2:</b> <span className="poke-data">{poke.type_2}</span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>Attack:</b> <span className="poke-data">{poke.attack}</span></td>
                                            <td><b>Defense:</b> <span className="poke-data">{poke.defense}</span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>HP:</b> <span className="poke-data">{poke.hp}</span></td>
                                            <td><b>Speed:</b> <span className="poke-data">{poke.speed}</span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>Ability 1:</b> <span className="poke-data">{poke.ability_1}</span></td>
                                            <td><b>Ability 2:</b> <span className="poke-data">{poke.ability_2}</span></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><b>Pokebase:</b> <span className="poke-data">{poke.pokebase}</span></td>
                                            <td><b>Pokedex entry:</b> <a href={poke.pokedex}> <span className="poke-data">{poke.pokemon}</span></a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                }
            })

        );
    };
}


class Maincontent extends React.Component{
    renderPokedesc(id){
        return (<Pokedescription pokeid = {id} />);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="maincontent">
                {this.renderPokedesc(10)}
            </div>
        );
    };
}


class Pokedex extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        pokemon_id: 1
    };
  }

  renderSidebar(){
    return (
        <Sidebar />
    );
  }

  renderMaincontent(){
    return (
        <Maincontent />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="pokedex-wrapper">
            {this.renderSidebar()}
            <div className="main-content-wrapper">
            {this.renderMaincontent()}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <Pokedex />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` has a different context than you are expecting. In your case `this` doesn't have `renderSidebaritem` because it's in the context of an anonymous function and not your component class (`this` is `undefined`).

The solution is to use an arrow function instead of a regular function. Arrow functions do not create a new context but instead use the surrounding context - `this` will be the instance of the class.

```
data.map(poke => this.renderSidebaritem(poke.pokemon))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
render() {
    let self = this;
    return (
      <div className="sidebar">
        <h1>POKEDEX</h1>
        <hr />
        <ul>
          {
            data.map(function (poke, key) {
              self.renderSidebaritem(poke.title);
            })
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside data map you are not using arrow functions, so it has it's own "this" scope. So even if you bind it, it's not gonna work.
You can either use arrow functions instead, or create a variable to store the "this" of the Sidebar class.

```
render(){
    return (
        <div className="sidebar">
            <h1>POKEDEX</h1>
            <hr/>
            {
              data.map((poke) => {
                this.renderSidebaritem(poke.pokemon)
              })
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

or

```
const sidebarThis = this;
render(){
    return (
        <div className="sidebar">
            <h1>POKEDEX</h1>
            <hr/>
            {
              data.map((poke) => {
                sidebarThis.renderSidebaritem(poke.pokemon)
              })
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bind` if you don't want to use arrow function:

```
data.map(function(poke){
  this.renderSidebaritem(poke.pokemon) // <- This line causes the issue. 
}.bind(this))
```

> But make it a habit to use arrow function whenever you are dealing
>   with callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

The "this" you are using in side maps function belongs to the scope of that function not to the scope of the class. Use arrow functions or inline bind().

Answer (score 0):

```
render(){
   return (
       <div className="sidebar">
           <h1>POKEDEX</h1>
           <hr/>
           {
             data.map(poke => { this.renderSidebaritem(poke.pokemon) })
           }
       </div>
   );
}
```